# Barra de navegação fixa da erro quando utiliza Carousel

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, carousel

Quando esta no modo mobile a barra de navegação fixa anda na rolagem utilizando o carousel, somente no modo mobile isso acontece
ja tentei e não sei como resolver

[Exemplo](https://jsfiddle.net/ennoorec/)

Answer (score 0):

Adicione este css para forçar com que ela não seja fixa em mobiles:

```
@media (max-width:480px) {
  .navbar-fixed-top {
    position: initial !important;
  }
}
```